Calculating the amount of torque applied to to stop a rod rotating at some angular velocity
Consider a Rod AB, having length $l$ with non uniform mass density $\lambda (x) $  a function of length from the end A, is rotating at an angular velocity $\omega$ with fixed end A and free end B. Plane of rotation of rod is perpendicular to the fixed axis of rotation passing through A.
What is the torque that should be applied at a point which is $x$ units away from the fixed end A to stop the rod in time $t$.
(Edit : from the comment below,I got that it will take infinite torque to stop that instantly, so I've removed the words threshold and instantly.)

Origin of the problem, we were doing some construction work and a pole of wood was to be placed vertically, we tied it at a point just below the upper end of the pole and fixed it's lower end by an obstacle, and pulled the rope ( from a height). But in middle when it was like 75°-80° from the ground, due to some reason two of us slept it. Rest of us we not able to stop it from falling back. When it was falling, because the motion was not completely free  , ( we were holding the rope) so after accelerating to some velocity, I'm assuming it was falling at some fixed angular velocity. I want to calculate, How much force we all should have applied to stop that pole ?
In case of a rod, any amount of torque can stop it, it's a matter of time it will take, like the brakes applied to a running bicycle eventually stop the tyre, time depends on how much forcibly you have applied the brakes. So I want to find out the minimum force that will stop the rod instantly.
I tried to do calculations, by calculating the Moment of Inertia, it's angular momentum but the problem I'm facing is the point of application of torque, I'm not sure how to proceed from there is it lever effect or just simply torque that will counter the rod's inertia,but the mass isn't at a fixed point so I'm stuck here.
Kindly help. Thank You.

I would rather be more concerned about the angle at which you were holding the rope when the rod was near the $77^\circ$ where it began to slip. However, I want to point out that you are almost already understanding the problem when you talked about running bicycle, "time depends on how much forcibly you have applied the brakes"—the answer is, if you want it to be instantaneous, you have to apply infinite torque. The concept of forces and torques become meaningless when you do that. You should talk about momentum instead.

I would have resolved the components for the angle we were holding the rope. But for infinite torque, like I can apply some force to stop a bike tire in very less time (almost instantly) does that mean that I've applied infinite torque? Will that infinite torque would be able to stop a tyre of a truck? I meant there should be a threshold limit that would be enough for a particular case. It seems logical that when time approaches 0, it could make the expression infinite ( which I need to find). Can we do such calculation for some finite time say 1 second for stopping that?

Human brains, hands, etc, cannot work faster than one microsecond. It is NOT instantaneous. It is less than some very short time. And then it is not infinite. That's what you should be considering.
